# Object creation from Xml Return and Modification

Tags: php, xml, oop

Let's say I have a Class (simplified):

```
class User
{
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $address;
    public $city;
    public $state;
    public $zip;
    public $phoneNumber;
}
```

now let's say I have an XML return which looks like:

```
[User] => SimpleXMLElement Object
       (
          [firstName] => foo
          [lastName] => bar              
          [address] => 3111 east 1
          [city] => oneVille
          [state] => Fo
          [zip] => 51155
          [phoneNumber] => 5551112222
        )
```

Is there an easy way to create a User object off that return so I could than modify the values? Assuming that the return ment to be fit my User class.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly:

```
$userXml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$userObj = new User();
foreach($userXml as $key => $value) {
    $userObj->$key = (string)$value;
}
```

I'm not sure I've got the iteration interface right, but that's close.

Comment: figured as much, wasn't sure if there was a way of doing it without iterating through the values but just pushing the particular set into the object. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the constructor of your `User` class to accept an object of type `SimpleXMLElement` and use its value to populate your User; although if your user objects aren't doing anything other than holding the data, you've not really gained anything by having that class in the first place:

```
class User
{
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $address;
    public $city;
    public $state;
    public $zip;
    public $phoneNumber;

    public function __construct( SimpleXMLElement $xml )
    {
        $this->firstName = isset( $xml->firstName ) ? $xml->firstName : '';
        ...
        $this->phoneNumber = isset( $xml->phoneNumber ) ? $xml->phoneNumber : '';
    }
}
$user = new User( $your_xml_element_object_here );
```

You could also use Frank's foreach loop to populate them dynamically, but presumably you would only want to assign those fields that already exist in your class definition.